# physical significance of dirac in inverse laplace

Tags: inverse-laplace

i was working through [this old electronics SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275780/nodal-analysis-with-laplace-of-simple-circuit). Initial conditions have the capacitor voltage and inductor current both zero.

[image: circuit]

Using Laplace we can find the voltage across the inductor, ${30s/(s+5)}$, which i then take the inverse Laplace of in MCAD and the result is:

[image: inverse laplace]

This represents the voltage across the inductor when the circuit is suddenly excited at t=0. The second term is understandable, a decaying exponential.

What is the physical significance of the dirac term (times 30)?

I simulated the circuit in [transients analysis](https://www.atpdraw.net/) software and here is a plot of the first 100mS or so of voltage (switch closed at t=0.1 in the simulation).  It eventually dies down to zero as expected.

[image: initial voltage]

Comment: Inductance is defined by the relationship $$ V = L \frac{dI}{dt}$$ When a switch is closed, the current changes immediately, giving a brief "infinite" voltage. Mathematically, plotting current as a function of time gives a jump discontinuity, and the derivatives of jump discontinuities are deltas.

Comment: Thanks @NinadMunshi.  So the numerical software simulation is wrong.  It doesn't report the "infinite" spike, it approximates it just under 20kV.